# More responsive stars in tag popups

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching, ignored-tags

One of the things I like about Stack Overflow is how fast everything is, from loading time to interactive tasks - posting comments, voting, etc.

The one task a bit at odd with all this is the ignore/favor tag functionality, especially the ignore one. Sometime I want to ignore a tag but I found I don't do it because 1) it's going to take something like 5 seconds to open the tooltip (after moving the mouse over it) 2) it's going to take another 5 seconds to favor the tag (waiting for the web request response). Only then can I ignore the tag.

Wouldn't it be possible to at least skip the second step? Just let us click twice on the star without having to wait for the web request response. To avoid any race condition, perhaps a timestamp could be attached to the request, then only the latest one needs to be processed.

Perhaps there's a better way, but basically anything that could make ignoring/favoring a tag faster would be great.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't take anything like 5 seconds here (less than 1sec for sure). You can also add tags directly to your fav/ignored lists on the front page (right side) and from your profile (which allows you to fav/ignore with a wildcard too).

Comment: Yes, actually I've added many tags through various methods. I still think that something like "liking" / "disliking" something should be as simple as pressing a button. If the feature could be improved in any way that would be great.